# 2d rotation 1000 random points around one point

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, 2d

I generate 1000 random points, and I'd like to rotate the points, around some point defined by 
x and y.

I've used:

```
px = Math.cos(theta) * (px-ox) - Math.sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox

py = Math.sin(theta) * (px-ox) + Math.cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
```

but the problem is that points start to converge, to rotation point after rotating for some time.

Here is the javascript code.
http://www.kaotik.si/rotation1.html

what I am doing wrong ?

the iteration section of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tocke.length; i++) 
{
    px = tocke[i]["x"];
    py = tocke[i]["y"];
    r = tocke[i]["r"];
    g = tocke[i]["g"];
    b = tocke[i]["b"];

    theta = 0.1;
    ox = centerX;
    oy = centerY;
    px = Math.cos(theta) * (px-ox) - Math.sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox
    py = Math.sin(theta) * (px-ox) + Math.cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
    tocke[i]["x"] = px;
    tocke[i]["y"] = py;

    draw_point(px,py,r,g,b,1);
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks for solving the problem:
I did have to change to:

```
theta = 0.1;
ox = centerX;
oy = centerY;
tmpX = Math.cos(theta) * (px-ox) - Math.sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox
tmpY = Math.sin(theta) * (px-ox) + Math.cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
tocke[i]["x"] = tmpX;
tocke[i]["y"] = tmpY;
draw_point(px,py,r,g,b,1);
```

Comment: If px, py is the rotation point, what is ox,oy?

Comment: ox, oy is point the point arround which i am rotating the 1000 points.
and it is constant, it is set to 500, 500

Comment: px and py are cordinate of the point i am going to rotate, for theta, i do it in the loop for all the 1000 points.

Comment: You should not execute `sin` and `cos` that often, especially since their results are constants actually.

Answer (score 4):

You're reassigning `px` **before** it gets used in the calculation for `py`.

Comment: That's pretty much it.  Make two new variables for either the old-values, or the new values, calculate the new values and assign them back to the object. Either way, don't overwrite obj.x and then use the new value in the calculation for obj.y.